# In Ant Design EditableProTable, how to listen to onChange of a ValueEnum type (`select` tag)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

```
//Column config that needs to listen.
{
  title: 'Contract Status',
  dataIndex: 'ConStatus',
  valueType: 'select',
  key: 'ConStatus',
  filters: true,
  valueEnum: {
    Pending: { text: 'Pending', status: 'Warning' },
    Completed: { text: 'Completed', status: 'Success' },
    Terminated: { text: 'Terminated', status: 'Error' },
  },
  render: (_) => <a>{_}</a>,
  onCell:
    (record: PlantationListItem, rowIndex: any) => { 
      return {
         onChange: (e: any) => {                        <----- not listening
          alert(JSON.stringify(record.ConStatus)); //  not working

          //send POST REQUEST 

          // Refresh page
        },
        
      };
    }
},
```

https://procomponents.ant.design/en-US/components/editable-table/

I want to change status of the ContractStatus column and refresh the table again.